# Is there a way to base the rights to publish a form in Episerver based on the presence of webhooks?

Tags: forms, webhooks, episerver

We use two user groups in Episerver, web editors and extended web editors. Normally, both should be able to create and publish forms. However, only extended web editors should be able to publish a form if one or more webhooks have been specified. How, if at all possible, can this be achieved?

My initial thought was to use an InitializationModule and add a handler for the PublishingContent event, but I have not figured out a way way to access the webhooks information.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you need - this one can be a good starting point https://devblog.gosso.se/2020/03/add-webhook-programmatically-episerver-form/ - they do pretty the same (accessing forms web hooks in content event); more info can be found googling for `CallWebhookAfterSubmissionActor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the PublishingContent event worked fine and I got the answer I needed regarding the webhooks info on: [world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum](https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/-Episerver-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2020/7/is-there-a-way-to-base-the-rights-to-publish-a-form-in-episerver-based-on-the-presence-of-webhooks/)

My mistake was to do this when trying to access this info:

```
myBlock.Property["CallWebhookAfterSubmissionActor"]
```

From this I could extract a list of webhooks, but it was always empty. What I had not realized was that since we are using a custom actor, the name of the property must match the name of that class. This is basically what I ended up with:

```
myBlock.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<CustomWebhookActorModel>>("CustomCallWebhookAfterSubmissionActor")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the `PublishingContent` event to see if the prequisites are met.

If not, you can cancel the event with an intuitive message to let the editor know they're not permitted to publish the content (i.e. the form in this case).

Example: https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Janaka-Fernando/Dates/2015/4/adding-custom-logic-to-your-publishing-step/